# Zoom meeting ios SDK is not working while bridging from react native

Tags: javascript, objective-c, react-native, bridge, zoom-sdk

In obj C, I have added a `UIViewcontroller` from which zoom sdk will be intiated in `viewDidLoad` method as below,

```
// ZoomViewController.m
@implementation ZoomViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self setupSDK:@"MY_APP_JWT_TOKEN"];
}
- (void)setupSDK:(NSString *)jwtToken {
  MobileRTCSDKInitContext *context = [[MobileRTCSDKInitContext alloc] init];
  context.domain = @"zoom.us";
  context.enableLog = YES;
  BOOL sdkInitSuc = [[MobileRTC sharedRTC] initialize:context];
  if (sdkInitSuc) {
    MobileRTCAuthService *authService = [[MobileRTC sharedRTC] getAuthService];
    if (authService) {
      authService.delegate = self;
      authService.jwtToken = jwtToken;
      [authService sdkAuth];
    }
  }
}

- (void)onMeetingStateChange:(MobileRTCMeetingState)state {
  NSLog(@"Meeting state: %ld", (long)state);
}

- (void)onMeetingReady:(MobileRTCMeetingState)state {
  NSLog(@"Meeting ready: %ld", (long)state);
}

-(void)startzoommeeting {
  MobileRTCMeetingService *meetingService = [[MobileRTC sharedRTC] getMeetingService];
  if (meetingService) {
    meetingService.delegate = self;
    [meetingService customizeMeetingTitle:@"Sample meeting title"];
    MobileRTCMeetingStartParam4WithoutLoginUser *user = [[MobileRTCMeetingStartParam4WithoutLoginUser alloc] init];
    user.userType = MobileRTCUserType_APIUser;
    user.meetingNumber = kMeetingNumber;
    user.userName = KuserName;
    user.isAppShare = NO;
    user.zak = @"MY_APP_JWT_TOKEN";
    [meetingService startMeetingWithStartParam: user];
  };
}
#pragma mark - MobileRTCAuthDelegate
- (void)onMobileRTCAuthReturn:(MobileRTCAuthError)returnValue {
    switch (returnValue) {
        case MobileRTCAuthError_Success:
[self startzoommeeting]; //  After the SDK initiation success 
            break;
      case MobileRTCAuthError_Unknown:
            NSLog(@"Client JWT Token authentication is invalid.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"SDK Authorization failed with MobileRTCAuthError: %u", returnValue);
    }
}
 
 
// ZoomViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileRTC/MobileRTC.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MobileRTCMeetingServiceDelegate, MobileRTCAuthDelegate>
@end
 
// ZoomViewControllerBridge.m -- bridge_file

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(presentZoomView) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject];
          if (window) {
            UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
            if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
                UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)rootViewController;
                ZoomViewController *zoomVC = [[ZoomViewController alloc] init];
                [navController pushViewController:zoomVC animated:YES];
          }
     });
}
```

In React Native , I'm calling the native code through bridge as below

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { ZoomViewControllerBridge } = NativeModules;
ZoomViewControllerBridge.presentZoomView();
```

The Zoom SDK initialisation was successful, and the following line of code `meetingService startMeetingWithStartParam: user` was executed; however, nothing happens after that. When I try the same flow in native code, the delegate method `onMeetingStateChange` is called, but it's not getting called through the bridge.

What am I missing?